# symfony extract data from entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hello i have a problem i would like to retrieve data from my entity in Symfony here is the code:

```
  public function indexAction(Request $request , $id)
    {

        $getDoctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $email = $getDoctrine->getRepository('desplayBundle:people')->find($id);
        dump($email);

        return $this->render('emailBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array());
    }
```

I would like to retrieve the data inside my controller and not in twig.

Comment: what do you retrieve with dump($email)? what is your expected output?

Comment: i retrieve all the content from that row in entity in that id i gave but i would like to extract only the email from that colunm

Comment: @erevos13 Did you define getters and setters in model?

Comment: Have you getters and setters for you entity ? Like : `public function getEmail()`in your `People` Entity ?

Comment: yes yes all that... but how can i extract here.?

Comment: @erevos13 dump($email->getEmal())

Comment: ι want to get from that row in entity the one column where i have for the specific email for that id.

Comment: i can i do that:$sendEmail = $email->getEmail();

Comment: i find it......thank you very muchhhhhhh...!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get email from user ?

```
public function indexAction(Request $request , $id)
{

    $getDoctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $getDoctrine->getRepository('desplayBundle:people')->find($id);
    $email = $user->getEmail();

    return $this->render('emailBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that in your entity you've getter of your data and then add this line of code instead of your dump.

```
 public function indexAction(Request $request , $id)
 {

     $getDoctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $email = $getDoctrine->getRepository('desplayBundle:people')->find($id);
     $data = $email->getData();

     return $this->render('emailBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array());
 }
```